# から and ので formation/conjugation differences

Tags: conjugations, conjunctions, morphology

Consider the case when `から` and　`ので` follows a noun, な-adjective, or noun-equivalent:

> から：静か**だ**から... "Because it is quiet..." (Subjective causality)
>
> ので：静か**な**ので... "Because it is quiet..." (Objective causality)

**(Question)** What causes the difference in the parts in bold above?

---

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`から` 'since, because' attaches to a clause, whereas `で` 'with (the reason being)' attaches to a noun. `静かだ` is an indicative clause (ordinary sentence), so you can simply attach `から`, but not `で`.

> - 静かだから
> - × 静かだで

In order to use `で`, you have to have a noun. To do that, you use the formal noun (or nominalizer) `の` taking an appositive clause. In appositive clauses and relative clauses, na-adjectives take the adnominal ending `～な`.

> - × 静かなのから
> - 静かなので